# Regex matching optional section

Tags: php, regex, escaping

So I have two possible strings here for example.

```
/user/name
```

and

```
/user/name?redirect=1
```

I'm trying to figure out the proper regex to match either with a result of:

```
Array ([0] => /user/name [1] => user [2] => name)
```

I think the part I'm having an issue with is that the question mark and the GET query after it are optional and will only be there some of the time. I've tried many different things and can't seem to come up with a regex to match the strings whether the ?** is there or not.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried using an optional group? Please post what you have so far.

Comment: one I have at the moment /\/(.*)\/(.*)(\?)(.*)/i but that doesn't return a match if the ?redirect=1 is not present

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a regex,

Use [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), and [explode()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$result = parse_url("/here/is/a/path?query=string");
$pieces  = explode("/", $result['path']);
```

Comment: thats a good idea, let me give that a whirl and see if it works with what I'm trying to do

Comment: I was able to get that to work with what I needed. Thank you sir and thank you everyone else!

Answer (score 1):

`?` is the "zero-or-one" quantifier.  So you could append `(\?.*)?` to your regex, which will optionally match zero or one instances of a literal question-mark followed by any number of characters.

Comment: the only issue with that is then the array match yields. [2] => name?redirect=1     I need it to yield only name. [3] could be the value after the ?

Answer (score 0):

In regex you can specify something as optional using the `?` parameter. So for instance, the regex `n?ever` matches `ever` and `never`.

In your case, you might want something like `/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)(\?redirect=1)?`

This will match `/.../...` (given the "..." consist of letters and numbers) or `/.../...?redirect=1`

If there are more possible flags that could come after the question mark than simply `redirect=1`, try the more general:

`/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)(\?[A-Za-z0-9]+=[A-Za-z0-9]+)?(&[A-Za-z0-9]+=[A-Za-z0-9]+)*`

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('{^/(user)/(name)(?=\?redirect=1)?$}', $subject, $matches);
```

This is a [look ahead assertion](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php). It won't be included in the match itself.

But like the other answers suggest you shouldn't use regex to parse URLs. Just posting the actual answer to the specific question for completeness.